# Why does the Apple Watch use a wireless charger, even though such a charger works slower than a MagSafe-like wired connector would?

Tags: battery-charging, wireless, design, charging, wireless-charging

The Apple Watch includes a built-in lithium polymer battery (a few hundred mAh; slightly more than 3.75 V) which is recharged using a wireless inductive charging cable.  The cable does use magnets to attach to the back of the watch; but the charging is still done wirelessly.

Andreas Ødegård points out in a [2013 article](http://www.pocketables.com/2013/02/to-me-the-most-interesting-part-about-the-pebble-smartwatch-is-the-connector.html) on the Pocketables website that:

- Wireless charging is slow.
- Waterproofing a micro-USB jack is hard to do, especially on a tiny watch.
- The Pebble smartwatch "has its own proprietary connector. It’s a mix between a pogo pin connector and a magnetic connector, using two magnets on the side of a pogo pin connector to provide charging."
- The Pebble watch's connector is better than a wireless one: it gives you the high speed of wired charging, is durable, and is waterproof.

It *does* seem possible to charge the Apple Watch faster by gaining access to its concealed "diagnostic port". But some disassembly may be required.  Also, once you remove the diagnostic port cover, the watch might no longer be waterproof at all.  And, I don't know enough about electronics to say whether or not such faster charging could possibly damage the battery or cause other problems.

Why does the Apple Watch use wireless charging instead of a magnetic wired charging connector?

Note:  It's definitely not a patent issue, since Apple themselves are the owner of the MagSafe power connector patent.

Comment: Because now you have a fully wireless watch. Never underestimate the power of hype.

Comment: It doesn't use "wireless" charging, it uses magnetic induction charging ;)

Comment: Same reason people prefer inductive wii remote charging, connivence/ease of use.

Comment: Dear all:  I have changed the question from opinion-based to fact-based.  What do you think of it now?

Comment: @unforgettableid the changes don't change much. This is opinion based because unless we have access to internal Apple documentation on product development, it's all speculation. It's enough to say Apple was content with the charge speed via wireless.

Comment: @Passerby:  Information sometimes leaks out of companies, whether via [former employees](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4416065), via leaked documents, or via other methods.

Comment: A) In chat, MickLH added: `I would keep the charging rate very low to avoid uncomfortable heat on the user's wrist`. B) He also mentioned [another reason](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23138412#23138412) — that there are ways that a drop of water can get stuck inside a female wired charging connector, especially if the user does silly things (as some users sometimes do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest Apple chose magnetic induction charging for two reasons. Firstly aesthetics, no unsightly connector and secondly practicality since connectors can deteriorate get damaged and are a potential site for moisture ingress.

Comment: Yes, for moisture ingress...